# How is the structure of this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> By and by Pooh and Piglet came along. Pooh was telling Piglet in a
>   singing voice that it didn't seem to matter, if he didn't get any
>   fatter, and he didn't think he was getting any fatter, what he did;
>   and Piglet was wondering how long it would be before his haycorn came
>   up.

This is from "The House At Pooh Corner". I couldn't grasp the structure of this sentence, so I asked it to native English speakers. A person said "what he did" is an older British phrase that roughly means "this is what he did". Another person said that "it didn't seem to matter, {if he didn't get any fatter, and he didn't think he was getting any fatter,} what he did". Which is correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should understand that second sentence as *Pooh was telling Piglet in a singing voice that it didn't seem to matter what he did* - with "parenthetical" *if he didn't get any fatter* being "ungrammatically" inserted to clarify *exactly **what*** "didn't matter" - further qualified by the fact that *he didn't think he was getting any fatter*. I can't remember the *exact* context (it was over half-a-century for me! :), but there might be some *deliberate* confusion about who "he" is in all those instances (explicitly identifying "Piglet" as the final "subject" is a bit stylistically quirky).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to a song sung by Pooh elsewhere in the story - see winniethepooh_uk.tripod.com/poohbear/id14.htm (scroll down a couple of paragraphs).

I'm pretty sure the sense is "I don't get any fatter no matter what I do", or "...whatever I do". It is shortened to "what I do" to fit the rhythm of the song.

Comment: That's it! Here's Pooh "original" song... *I could spend a happy morning Seeing Roo, \ I could spend a happy morning Being Pooh. \ For it doesn't really matter, \ If I don't get any fatter \ **(And I don't get any fatter),** \ What I do.* Milne deliberately "playing" with language by inserting that parenthetical highlighted element in a quirky way that would *never* pass muster with pedants, but is perfectly comprehensible (and *amusingly* so) to the target audience (children).

Comment: ...there wasn't room to include the actual link in that comment, so [here it is](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=d1FlAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA107&dq=pooh+%22I+don%27t+get+any+fatter%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAtonEp4jnAhUbTxUIHR47BlwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=pooh%20%22I%20don't%20get%20any%20fatter%22&f=false) for anyone who want to read the second (Rabbit-inspired) verse.

Comment: When approaching Milne’s work it’s worthwhile understanding that the animals of Hundred Acre Wood speak and view the English language from the perspective of children.  They misuse and misspell words; they are playful with grammar.  I encourage you to read it aloud.  Surely one of life’s greatest treasures, should I live long enough, will be to read these stories to my grandchildren.